# Do floating plants on a quiet body of water significantly affect the evaporation?

Tags: botany

A situation such as a pond where a plant like duck weed covers essentially all visible surface water  : Is evaporation slowed or stopped ?

Comment: To what degree are you or are you not interested in including the plants' evapotranspiration rate into the evaporation rate of the pond water? In other words, are you more interested in the net change of water level or in the specific mechanism of surface evaporation from the pond surface?

Comment: Actually I am interested in heat loss . I cover the pond with Styrofoam panels in cold ( air below 50 F) weather. The Koi don't care but I have tropicals in it; Danios .They have tolerated water temp. down to 50 F  . I want to avoid putting on the panels for an occasional cold night.